# HTML5 Canvas ctx.fill() fills outside the stroke area

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working with the virtual sky library, https://github.com/slowe/VirtualSky. The library tries to show a visual representation of the sky. The library is built on html canvas. In the original code, the milky way line is drawn as a line with `ctx.stroke()` and everything works fine. I tried adding `ctx.fill()` to fill in the milky way area but for some coordinates/dates canvas fills outside the stroked area. I added the two images that represents the issue. In the filled version, notice that it fills also some other area outside the milky way line. I spent much time on the issue but couldn't figure out why the canvas fills outside the drawn area.

#### Without ctx.fill()

[image: Without ctx.fill()]

---

#### With ctx.fill()

[image: With ctx.fill()]

---

#### Here is the code that draws the Milky Way line :

```
VirtualSky.prototype.drawGalaxy = function(colour){
    if(!this.galaxy || !this.showgalaxy) return this;
    if(!colour) colour = this.col.galaxy;
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = colour;
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.4)";
    this.ctx.lineWidth = (this.gal.lineWidth || 0.75);
    this.ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    var p,pa,pb,i,c,maxl,dx,dy;
    maxl = this.maxLine(5);

    for(c = 0; c < this.galaxy.length; c++){

        // We will convert all the galaxy outline coordinates to radians
        if(!this.gal.processed){
            for(i = 1; i < this.galaxy[c].length; i++) this.galaxy[c][i] *= this.d2r;
        }

        // Get a copy of the current shape
        p = this.galaxy[c].slice(0);

        // Get the colour (first element)
        p.shift();
        // Set the initial point to null
        pa = null;

        // Now loop over joining the points
        for(i = 0; i < p.length; i+=2){
            pb = this.radec2xy(p[i], p[i+1]);
            if(i==0) this.ctx.moveTo(pb.x,pb.y);
            else{
                dx = Math.abs(pa.x-pb.x);
                dy = Math.abs(pa.y-pb.y);
                if(!isNaN(dx) && !isNaN(dy)){
                    // Basic error checking: if the line is very long we need to normalize to other side of sky
                    if(dx >= maxl || dy >= maxl) this.ctx.moveTo(pb.x,pb.y);
                    this.ctx.lineTo(pb.x,pb.y);
                }else{
                    this.ctx.moveTo(pb.x,pb.y);
                }
            }
            pa = pb;
        }
    }
    // We've converted the galaxy to radians
    this.gal.processed = true;
    this.ctx.stroke();

    this.ctx.fill();

//  I added this ctx.fill() here which causes the problem.

    return this;
};
```

#### Json data for the milky way lines

```js
{
  "galaxy": [
    ["#396bad", 254.1778, -21.5124, 253.6146, -22.5310, 253.2638, -27.7008, 251.9368, -29.7742, 249.7919, -29.7867, 247.8000, -28.4406, 246.5570, -26.9571, 244.6278, -25.8787, 242.5067, -26.0070, 241.5945, -25.3687, 240.7208, -23.0525, 239.5973, -22.3533, 238.6863, -23.5322, 238.7180, -25.7313, 239.4131, -28.0723, 238.6475, -30.8747, 239.9512, -34.4963, 240.4545, -37.0030, 238.8220, -39.1709, 235.6101, -41.6744, 234.5926, -42.9833, 235.6221, -44.6917, 235.5743, -46.4283, 232.6913, -48.4186, 228.3087, -49.7552, 225.9823, -50.6267, 221.4249, -52.5289, 216.0338, -54.6596, 209.0229, -55.3209, 202.9102, -56.0362, 196.2626, -56.3616, 191.7337, -57.1169, 184.7426, -59.1857, 180.5514, -58.8402, 175.1997, -58.5802, 170.6339, -57.6749, 168.3549, -56.2380, 163.3607, -54.7001, 159.2106, -51.3301, 154.8495, -47.2975, 150.0574, -45.2411, 146.8211, -44.7221, 145.5418, -45.4794, 145.6709, -46.1571, 149.5391, -48.3145, 150.7915, -49.6707, 150.0747, -51.0247, 147.4159, -49.8497, 144.3472, -47.8592, 142.7713, -47.5886, 142.7304, -48.1825, 141.8590, -48.7921, 143.8702, -51.7563, 146.7533, -53.8733, 146.7337, -54.7900, 145.4937, -55.0315, 136.3994, -53.7185, 133.1890, -53.9932, 132.3952, -55.2722, 133.9782, -56.3603, 137.5581, -56.8447, 142.3823, -56.7640, 147.1253, -56.7384, 149.2668, -57.3424, 151.0831, -57.4354, 153.9265, -58.4216, 157.9421, -58.9774, 159.0422, -59.6771, 157.5067, -60.3507, 155.1830, -59.7783, 151.9601, -59.2083, 149.2887, -59.3163, 148.3379, -59.9243, 149.9157, -61.4340, 154.0475, -62.1249, 155.9994, -62.2575, 159.2582, -63.5263, 165.5091, -63.4204, 167.1619, -62.8290, 170.1596, -61.3662, 172.9661, -61.4156, 176.0518, -62.9133, 179.3437, -64.2607, 181.9387, -65.3282, 184.3779, -69.3924, 188.2568, -70.9570, 194.7347, -71.2607, 199.7570, -70.2394, 204.1730, -68.8427, 209.0938, -67.8511, 216.7510, -68.0095, 221.9748, -67.1396, 227.5494, -66.2461, 234.5158, -64.3854, 240.5233, -61.8468, 244.0983, -60.4173, 251.3801, -59.1124, 253.2926, -57.4685, 254.7774, -56.3244, 261.4819, -54.4899, 265.8676, -50.8482, 268.8085, -48.0793, 269.9543, -46.3469, 270.5405, -43.6313, 270.6492, -42.3809, 271.0668, -41.1083, 273.1271, -38.6387, 274.8287, -36.5477, 276.5511, -33.8477, 275.4040, -33.1596, 275.2727, -30.5290, 276.8968, -28.1703, 277.9533, -25.4297, 278.6386, -22.3113, 279.4081, -19.7351, 280.9230, -17.4472, 281.9964, -15.6719, 282.8788, -13.6664, 283.3409, -11.0282, 284.5659, -8.4787, 285.8740, -5.6156, 287.7313, -3.1057, 289.7038, -1.0941, 290.4044, -0.0164, 290.7342, 1.1813, 291.9363, 0.4122, 292.8626, 0.7917, 295.5690, 0.8033, 297.0695, 1.1497, 297.0874, 2.1407, 295.9694, 2.3815, 294.6764, 2.5679, 294.4415, 3.7745, 295.0541, 5.1814, 296.9021, 5.9879, 297.7330, 6.5454, 297.6053, 8.4351, 298.6240, 10.2040, 298.1628, 13.5562, 299.1257, 15.5289, 302.8713, 15.4981, 305.5156, 16.1286, 308.1366, 16.6469, 308.7496, 18.5262, 307.5513, 19.8431, 307.7080, 20.7394, 309.0176, 21.5802, 308.7945, 23.5149, 309.4605, 24.2478, 310.5891, 24.9863, 310.3480, 26.0982, 308.9284, 26.8788, 309.1600, 27.5971, 311.8741, 29.1431, 313.3279, 32.0552, 313.9435, 35.1102, 314.9513, 36.1769, 319.2157, 38.0107, 320.5720, 39.7440, 321.0403, 40.9232, 321.8310, 41.6873, 323.6238, 44.8754, 325.1386, 46.0919, 328.0798, 46.8738, 332.6317, 47.1238, 338.1292, 47.4766, 344.7038, 47.6502, 346.4796, 47.7702, 351.3753, 46.7280, 355.1420, 46.2097, 359.5920, 46.1929, 4.3035, 46.2481, 8.0516, 45.6862, 10.5201, 45.7218, 12.3781, 45.1055, 16.3043, 45.2972, 19.0389, 44.8213, 23.6309, 45.0223, 30.7979, 43.0638, 32.8210, 42.8635, 40.6571, 43.7653, 43.6189, 43.8484, 46.6891, 42.5931, 45.3773, 41.6641, 41.7099, 41.8080, 39.3969, 41.6311, 36.5579, 40.8644, 36.3328, 39.9578, 39.0080, 38.9254, 43.4828, 39.0665, 47.0254, 39.2746, 50.5370, 39.3676, 53.6788, 39.5428, 55.7670, 38.8688, 57.1481, 37.3216, 57.2361, 35.7482, 56.6404, 33.7143, 57.1765, 32.1478, 58.8043, 30.8405, 59.9439, 30.9968, 61.4966, 33.3066, 61.4994, 36.0547, 61.1808, 38.6650, 61.7684, 40.0026, 63.8402, 40.1004, 71.4989, 34.6769, 75.3343, 31.9184, 79.7168, 29.0407, 81.0519, 25.1195, 82.1320, 22.0941, 83.6308, 17.4698, 85.5679, 15.1690, 86.9568, 12.6324, 87.7444, 8.8192, 91.3008, 6.1831, 92.8266, 2.6539, 94.6923, -2.1965, 97.7264, -6.0265, 102.5525, -9.6439, 104.6125, -11.6416, 105.1552, -14.2536, 108.2256, -18.5894, 109.6456, -25.3483, 111.2200, -27.2135, 111.2669, -32.1720, 114.7741, -37.8718, 116.9787, -42.4014, 117.0836, -45.1959, 116.1853, -48.6868, 118.8947, -50.1703, 123.5005, -49.9484, 125.9819, -48.8761, 122.1675, -44.3179, 122.4135, -42.9137, 124.6591, -42.8292, 129.1849, -46.1315, 132.5020, -47.4562, 134.3955, -47.4750, 135.7144, -46.3461, 131.5066, -42.8910, 132.0107, -42.0135, 137.8183, -45.2697, 139.3131, -45.0639, 139.6524, -44.1094, 136.9034, -40.6399, 136.6626, -38.9913, 139.6753, -40.1504, 144.8151, -42.6899, 150.5786, -42.3526, 153.6316, -43.0367, 155.7573, -42.5342, 156.1233, -41.0904, 152.5690, -38.5605, 148.4971, -37.7767, 141.2865, -38.2886, 135.1421, -35.9600, 129.8501, -32.1764, 126.2320, -28.4253, 122.1594, -21.3427, 118.5304, -12.7577, 116.3335, -8.7013, 112.8556, -6.4334, 109.1321, -2.3025, 108.1548, 0.0096, 107.9889, 5.4587, 106.7266, 8.9737, 103.4908, 11.8896, 101.3959, 15.0964, 99.5314, 17.7842, 97.6915, 19.7759, 96.9057, 21.2016, 90.6296, 24.9510, 88.0744, 27.4918, 86.0675, 31.0217, 85.2336, 32.7789, 81.6446, 36.8533, 79.8386, 39.1558, 78.6539, 44.2051, 77.5234, 45.5296, 73.0840, 46.1406, 69.0884, 46.5652, 66.4784, 48.5322, 65.0187, 50.6773, 63.1096, 51.4737, 60.4311, 51.8441, 60.2604, 52.7052, 63.6488, 52.7609, 65.6099, 53.0495, 68.0178, 52.7517, 68.0826, 53.7533, 63.1671, 54.9872, 57.4967, 55.4868, 58.4393, 56.1385, 60.5618, 56.2369, 62.6651, 56.7553, 62.6924, 57.7129, 59.3107, 59.2013, 50.7444, 59.4785, 45.7503, 59.6435, 43.3097, 60.6511, 38.7256, 61.5348, 35.7107, 62.5099, 30.2614, 62.7058, 27.5803, 63.4145, 23.1877, 65.0421, 18.5579, 65.6747, 13.7778, 67.5849, 11.2150, 68.1610, 7.5359, 67.6326, 5.1034, 66.7569, 2.2150, 66.1991, 0.2476, 66.2511, 355.2714, 64.4260, 350.1006, 62.9385, 344.4302, 62.4847, 339.3002, 60.4931, 333.4702, 58.8851, 331.1327, 59.4605, 330.9382, 61.9623, 340.6152, 65.1092, 343.2879, 66.7647, 343.3581, 70.1643, 341.1773, 70.8790, 336.6449, 73.1299, 333.5813, 75.1391, 324.6186, 76.5981, 322.6315, 75.9427, 319.0891, 73.7015, 314.8850, 71.0639, 315.6348, 68.7048, 315.4588, 66.8973, 313.0831, 64.8622, 312.0635, 62.5880, 314.0142, 60.2312, 313.6305, 59.4861, 311.8591, 59.3915, 309.8048, 58.5233, 310.2041, 57.1819, 306.9144, 55.9804, 304.6804, 54.7702, 305.2319, 53.7273, 307.7332, 52.9357, 308.4628, 52.2243, 308.0011, 51.7205, 306.5029, 51.7495, 304.1552, 50.3598, 302.5798, 48.5193, 302.1408, 47.1988, 300.7148, 46.6004, 299.0278, 47.0595, 297.2437, 46.8711, 295.7553, 46.0584, 294.7485, 44.4314, 292.7755, 41.4764, 288.6933, 39.1997, 287.4471, 37.8510, 287.5118, 36.7221, 289.2538, 36.0606, 290.9985, 36.0011, 292.6594, 35.2362, 292.3950, 34.1260, 291.2070, 33.2023, 288.4240, 33.0160, 287.0090, 32.3231, 286.5059, 31.2666, 287.0896, 29.6223, 286.5820, 27.3683, 285.1771, 25.5062, 283.1010, 23.9449, 281.0469, 22.8010, 279.4373, 21.4068, 279.1821, 19.6473, 279.7551, 18.2109, 280.9496, 17.7421, 282.6220, 17.1833, 283.2966, 16.1546, 283.0965, 15.0372, 281.5283, 14.0053, 280.0909, 12.9151, 278.6961, 11.5975, 277.0707, 10.5385, 275.4225, 9.5688, 273.4622, 8.5487, 270.9916, 7.3738, 269.3157, 5.7621, 268.8705, 4.4507, 269.5389, 3.1987, 271.0927, 2.6855, 273.2811, 2.5608, 275.4739, 3.3006, 278.1912, 5.0780, 281.9090, 8.5271, 284.1697, 11.3576, 286.2251, 14.0132, 286.3233, 15.1915, 286.1158, 15.5100, 285.7599, 16.6912, 286.7631, 18.2914, 287.1951, 19.3787, 286.9849, 20.8446, 289.3257, 22.5391, 291.9464, 25.4127, 292.4286, 28.5332, 293.4593, 30.5996, 297.2230, 32.4772, 299.7133, 35.0595, 303.4745, 35.0807, 304.1266, 34.0245, 303.6819, 30.3270, 300.8895, 28.8322, 296.8912, 28.3993, 294.9144, 27.6937, 294.5657, 26.6140, 296.1041, 25.9037, 297.3739, 25.6845, 297.8246, 24.4710, 295.9400, 22.7956, 293.0649, 21.4866, 291.1229, 20.8588, 290.3240, 19.7277, 290.6364, 18.7692, 292.0849, 18.3219, 293.1902, 17.8198, 293.1968, 16.4933, 292.2117, 15.0311, 290.2679, 13.8513, 288.7569, 12.5900, 288.6076, 10.9218, 288.7328, 9.7665, 287.2839, 8.8429, 285.5820, 8.1189, 284.2910, 7.0396, 283.2366, 5.8411, 282.9327, 3.8283, 282.5522, 3.2275, 280.8435, 2.7268, 279.3674, 2.2532, 278.3224, 1.3453, 278.2314, 0.7429, 279.1609, 1.5654, 279.5029, 0.9574, 279.8970, -0.2562, 281.6814, -0.8823, 283.4665, -1.5073, 284.0658, -2.4642, 282.9599, -3.4894, 281.1068, -3.6991, 279.0490, -4.0172, 278.1079, -5.1256, 278.2582, -6.7990, 279.0976, -9.4057, 278.6578, -11.6460, 277.3170, -14.1578, 276.1600, -16.6976, 275.8960, -19.1108, 275.5302, -21.8370, 274.9452, -24.2398, 272.9984, -26.4299, 270.0613, -28.0668, 268.2229, -29.8114, 268.5228, -30.2623, 267.9381, -32.1320, 267.1568, -33.2373, 265.0719, -33.6050, 262.2933, -32.3327, 261.2061, -30.0066, 261.2532, -27.8653, 261.7517, -26.3868, 262.0161, -24.8538, 263.5809, -22.8788, 265.0658, -21.1691, 265.8074, -19.4150, 266.6842, -18.7916, 268.0278, -18.7995, 268.7521, -17.4910, 268.3084, -15.3906, 266.9707, -13.3787, 264.9872, -12.4603, 262.4372, -12.2113, 260.5499, -13.2122, 258.4769, -14.8956, 256.1174, -16.7507, 254.4650, -18.3043, 253.6343, -20.3552, 254.1778, -21.5124, 254.1778, -21.5124, 254.1778, -21.5124],
    ["#396bad", 257.4284, -35.0782, 258.7567, -34.6776, 259.6113, -33.6806, 259.9750, -32.7946, 260.9776, -32.5946, 263.4189, -33.7211, 265.2841, -35.1551, 267.0684, -37.0106, 266.5317, -38.4758, 264.8234, -39.1661, 263.0403, -38.8168, 260.6629, -38.1140, 258.3247, -38.4735, 255.5110, -38.1878, 254.0470, -37.3602, 253.5295, -36.1222, 253.7763, -35.4603, 254.7476, -35.1875, 256.2938, -35.0264, 257.4284, -35.0782, 257.4284, -35.0782, 257.4284, -35.0782],
    ["#396bad", 254.4847, -39.5230, 255.2762, -39.2671, 257.3657, -39.9243, 258.7042, -41.3823, 258.3749, -43.2682, 257.0644, -43.3665, 254.3218, -40.8215, 254.6242, -40.4285, 254.4847, -39.5230, 254.4847, -39.5230, 254.4847, -39.5230],
    ["#396bad", 247.9505, -43.8132, 247.7714, -42.7233, 248.2105, -41.7101, 249.7280, -40.8373, 248.8720, -37.3180, 247.1054, -36.2799, 245.6020, -36.7984, 243.1195, -35.6949, 242.2253, -36.0340, 241.9943, -38.6050, 241.6221, -40.6326, 239.8163, -43.0489, 238.8334, -44.6762, 238.5119, -46.8016, 237.7857, -49.0401, 236.8718, -50.6695, 237.0713, -52.3828, 238.9693, -53.2821, 241.4236, -52.3398, 244.7950, -51.3601, 248.9798, -51.6343, 253.4436, -51.0624, 257.8767, -50.6966, 260.9423, -50.2581, 261.6140, -49.2459, 260.7624, -46.4869, 260.5888, -45.3986, 259.8614, -44.8904, 257.7870, -44.9484, 256.1962, -45.7995, 256.3613, -48.5425, 253.5419, -49.9573, 249.8040, -49.5087, 248.3220, -49.4156, 245.7227, -48.7635, 244.6261, -48.0299, 245.6396, -46.7119, 247.9407, -46.1849, 251.5170, -45.7312, 252.8143, -45.1508, 251.9638, -44.5626, 249.5206, -44.4962, 247.9505, -43.8132, 247.9505, -43.8132, 247.9505, -43.8132],
    ["#396bad", 231.8281, -52.4833, 233.5614, -52.5365, 234.4273, -52.7145, 236.0044, -53.8647, 236.5304, -55.8352, 237.3389, -57.1286, 230.3741, -58.8315, 226.4955, -59.1351, 221.0867, -60.4628, 220.9820, -59.2769, 221.7242, -59.0271, 223.2728, -57.1869, 226.5641, -55.0286, 228.1040, -54.5097, 229.9674, -52.9922, 231.8281, -52.4833, 231.8281, -52.4833, 231.8281, -52.4833],
    ["#396bad", 191.9931, -60.9308, 195.0383, -60.9157, 197.2513, -61.5730, 197.6589, -63.3081, 193.3910, -65.2609, 190.6198, -65.3102, 189.1651, -65.7997, 187.9019, -65.8296, 187.4866, -64.7787, 188.0292, -64.2788, 187.2718, -63.6037, 188.0759, -62.2722, 190.6559, -61.1093, 191.9931, -60.9308, 191.9931, -60.9308],
    ["#396bad", 132.7337, -37.5805, 133.0861, -38.9333, 132.3284, -39.7468, 129.7569, -39.4258, 127.1207, -38.0660, 124.9328, -36.1447, 124.8899, -34.6079, 124.7196, -32.9119, 125.9376, -32.1253, 127.3543, -32.6954, 128.6915, -33.7875, 129.6263, -35.1366, 131.7847, -36.5415, 132.7337, -37.5805, 132.7337, -37.5805],
    ["#396bad", 121.1825, -39.3994, 119.9070, -39.0295, 119.2840, -37.6001, 119.3245, -36.1550, 117.3621, -34.3430, 116.3134, -31.1424, 115.5167, -28.5014, 115.3112, -26.0891, 115.8367, -24.7060, 117.0334, -24.5218, 117.8897, -25.7087, 118.5145, -28.1509, 119.6664, -31.5362, 121.7083, -34.8713, 122.3366, -37.4519, 122.1419, -39.0037, 121.1825, -39.3994, 121.1825, -39.3994],
    ["#396bad", 305.9982, 40.1858, 309.8895, 39.3472, 311.2759, 37.2754, 311.2100, 35.4356, 310.1900, 34.7837, 308.6971, 34.9849, 307.5461, 36.5500, 305.0697, 37.7876, 304.5142, 39.0978, 305.1288, 40.0209, 305.9982, 40.1858]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Because your path is broken. Check your data's integrity, there is nothing we can do for you from here.

Comment: `> // Basic error checking: if the line is very long we need to normalize to other side of sky`

Have you tried to remove this normalization temporarily? It looks like there is a dot in the path that lays in `the other side of the sky` which shouldn't be there.

Comment: Share the actual data used to draw the path.

Comment: @extempl I added the data file. I tried removing the normalization line before , it helped for some of the coordinates/dates but not for others.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes that might be the issue but then why the path is drawn properly with only ctx.stroke

Comment: because `stroke()` doesn't care if your path is enclosed or not, for instance `moveTo(10,10), lineTo(15,10); moveTo(20,10); lineTo( 30, 10)` stroke will be able to draw the two lines, fill can't do anything

Comment: I think you already got the answer from the owner of the lib - this just was not implemented. Currently, lines stop where they are and start in a different position (out of the screen), while to keep filling work, it should not be prolonged out of the screen, but cut while on the edge of the screen which is not that easy task considering various views available in the lib and animations (so it should re-calc each tick to keep shape to be correct)

Answer (score 0):

As it was already said that could come from your data.
One way to easily check their integrity is to draw a small rectangle at each point location.

This way you can avoid checking every single number.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a little script to finde any jumps in the coordinates. Output:

```
Diff found at 342 with newX:   4.3035 and newY: 46.2481 and oldX:359.592 and oldY: 46.1929
Diff found at 624 with newX: 355.2714 and newY: 64.426  and oldX: 0.2476 and oldY: 66.2511
```

Therefor you need to add 360 to all the x Values inbetween 342 and 624.
You can see a demo of it here: https://jsfiddle.net/MisteriosM/18s0cpmq/43/

[image: Gold: old, Red = new]

Unfortunately I don't know if this really solves your problem since I do not know your draw code. You should update it to be able to use looping coordinates in future.

If you are Lazy and adding it works, here is the first line fixed (with js rounding errors):

```
["#396bad",254.1778,-21.5124,253.6146,-22.531,253.2638,-27.7008,251.9368,-29.7742,249.7919,-29.7867,247.8,-28.4406,246.557,-26.9571,244.6278,-25.8787,242.5067,-26.007,241.5945,-25.3687,240.7208,-23.0525,239.5973,-22.3533,238.6863,-23.5322,238.718,-25.7313,239.4131,-28.0723,238.6475,-30.8747,239.9512,-34.4963,240.4545,-37.003,238.822,-39.1709,235.6101,-41.6744,234.5926,-42.9833,235.6221,-44.6917,235.5743,-46.4283,232.6913,-48.4186,228.3087,-49.7552,225.9823,-50.6267,221.4249,-52.5289,216.0338,-54.6596,209.0229,-55.3209,202.9102,-56.0362,196.2626,-56.3616,191.7337,-57.1169,184.7426,-59.1857,180.5514,-58.8402,175.1997,-58.5802,170.6339,-57.6749,168.3549,-56.238,163.3607,-54.7001,159.2106,-51.3301,154.8495,-47.2975,150.0574,-45.2411,146.8211,-44.7221,145.5418,-45.4794,145.6709,-46.1571,149.5391,-48.3145,150.7915,-49.6707,150.0747,-51.0247,147.4159,-49.8497,144.3472,-47.8592,142.7713,-47.5886,142.7304,-48.1825,141.859,-48.7921,143.8702,-51.7563,146.7533,-53.8733,146.7337,-54.79,145.4937,-55.0315,136.3994,-53.7185,133.189,-53.9932,132.3952,-55.2722,133.9782,-56.3603,137.5581,-56.8447,142.3823,-56.764,147.1253,-56.7384,149.2668,-57.3424,151.0831,-57.4354,153.9265,-58.4216,157.9421,-58.9774,159.0422,-59.6771,157.5067,-60.3507,155.183,-59.7783,151.9601,-59.2083,149.2887,-59.3163,148.3379,-59.9243,149.9157,-61.434,154.0475,-62.1249,155.9994,-62.2575,159.2582,-63.5263,165.5091,-63.4204,167.1619,-62.829,170.1596,-61.3662,172.9661,-61.4156,176.0518,-62.9133,179.3437,-64.2607,181.9387,-65.3282,184.3779,-69.3924,188.2568,-70.957,194.7347,-71.2607,199.757,-70.2394,204.173,-68.8427,209.0938,-67.8511,216.751,-68.0095,221.9748,-67.1396,227.5494,-66.2461,234.5158,-64.3854,240.5233,-61.8468,244.0983,-60.4173,251.3801,-59.1124,253.2926,-57.4685,254.7774,-56.3244,261.4819,-54.4899,265.8676,-50.8482,268.8085,-48.0793,269.9543,-46.3469,270.5405,-43.6313,270.6492,-42.3809,271.0668,-41.1083,273.1271,-38.6387,274.8287,-36.5477,276.5511,-33.8477,275.404,-33.1596,275.2727,-30.529,276.8968,-28.1703,277.9533,-25.4297,278.6386,-22.3113,279.4081,-19.7351,280.923,-17.4472,281.9964,-15.6719,282.8788,-13.6664,283.3409,-11.0282,284.5659,-8.4787,285.874,-5.6156,287.7313,-3.1057,289.7038,-1.0941,290.4044,-0.0164,290.7342,1.1813,291.9363,0.4122,292.8626,0.7917,295.569,0.8033,297.0695,1.1497,297.0874,2.1407,295.9694,2.3815,294.6764,2.5679,294.4415,3.7745,295.0541,5.1814,296.9021,5.9879,297.733,6.5454,297.6053,8.4351,298.624,10.204,298.1628,13.5562,299.1257,15.5289,302.8713,15.4981,305.5156,16.1286,308.1366,16.6469,308.7496,18.5262,307.5513,19.8431,307.708,20.7394,309.0176,21.5802,308.7945,23.5149,309.4605,24.2478,310.5891,24.9863,310.348,26.0982,308.9284,26.8788,309.16,27.5971,311.8741,29.1431,313.3279,32.0552,313.9435,35.1102,314.9513,36.1769,319.2157,38.0107,320.572,39.744,321.0403,40.9232,321.831,41.6873,323.6238,44.8754,325.1386,46.0919,328.0798,46.8738,332.6317,47.1238,338.1292,47.4766,344.7038,47.6502,346.4796,47.7702,351.3753,46.728,355.142,46.2097,359.592,46.1929,364.3035,46.2481,368.0516,45.6862,370.5201,45.7218,372.3781,45.1055,376.3043,45.2972,379.0389,44.8213,383.6309,45.0223,390.7979,43.0638,392.821,42.8635,400.6571,43.7653,403.6189,43.8484,406.6891,42.5931,405.3773,41.6641,401.7099,41.808,399.3969,41.6311,396.5579,40.8644,396.3328,39.9578,399.008,38.9254,403.4828,39.0665,407.0254,39.2746,410.537,39.3676,413.6788,39.5428,415.767,38.8688,417.1481,37.3216,417.2361,35.7482,416.6404,33.7143,417.1765,32.1478,418.8043,30.8405,419.9439,30.9968,421.4966,33.3066,421.4994,36.0547,421.1808,38.665,421.7684,40.0026,423.8402,40.1004,431.4989,34.6769,435.3343,31.9184,439.71680000000003,29.0407,441.0519,25.1195,442.132,22.0941,443.6308,17.4698,445.5679,15.169,446.9568,12.6324,447.7444,8.8192,451.3008,6.1831,452.8266,2.6539,454.6923,-2.1965,457.7264,-6.0265,462.5525,-9.6439,464.6125,-11.6416,465.1552,-14.2536,468.2256,-18.5894,469.6456,-25.3483,471.22,-27.2135,471.2669,-32.172,474.7741,-37.8718,476.9787,-42.4014,477.0836,-45.1959,476.1853,-48.6868,478.8947,-50.1703,483.5005,-49.9484,485.9819,-48.8761,482.1675,-44.3179,482.4135,-42.9137,484.65909999999997,-42.8292,489.18489999999997,-46.1315,492.502,-47.4562,494.39549999999997,-47.475,495.7144,-46.3461,491.5066,-42.891,492.01070000000004,-42.0135,497.8183,-45.2697,499.31309999999996,-45.0639,499.6524,-44.1094,496.90340000000003,-40.6399,496.6626,-38.9913,499.6753,-40.1504,504.81510000000003,-42.6899,510.5786,-42.3526,513.6315999999999,-43.0367,515.7573,-42.5342,516.1233,-41.0904,512.569,-38.5605,508.4971,-37.7767,501.2865,-38.2886,495.1421,-35.96,489.8501,-32.1764,486.23199999999997,-28.4253,482.1594,-21.3427,478.5304,-12.7577,476.3335,-8.7013,472.8556,-6.4334,469.1321,-2.3025,468.1548,0.0096,467.9889,5.4587,466.7266,8.9737,463.4908,11.8896,461.3959,15.0964,459.5314,17.7842,457.6915,19.7759,456.9057,21.2016,450.6296,24.951,448.07439999999997,27.4918,446.0675,31.0217,445.2336,32.7789,441.64459999999997,36.8533,439.8386,39.1558,438.6539,44.2051,437.5234,45.5296,433.084,46.1406,429.0884,46.5652,426.47839999999997,48.5322,425.01869999999997,50.6773,423.1096,51.4737,420.4311,51.8441,420.2604,52.7052,423.6488,52.7609,425.6099,53.0495,428.01779999999997,52.7517,428.0826,53.7533,423.1671,54.9872,417.4967,55.4868,418.4393,56.1385,420.5618,56.2369,422.6651,56.7553,422.6924,57.7129,419.3107,59.2013,410.7444,59.4785,405.7503,59.6435,403.3097,60.6511,398.7256,61.5348,395.7107,62.5099,390.2614,62.7058,387.5803,63.4145,383.1877,65.0421,378.5579,65.6747,373.7778,67.5849,371.215,68.161,367.5359,67.6326,365.1034,66.7569,362.215,66.1991,360.2476,66.2511,355.2714,64.426,350.1006,62.9385,344.4302,62.4847,339.3002,60.4931,333.4702,58.8851,331.1327,59.4605,330.9382,61.9623,340.6152,65.1092,343.2879,66.7647,343.3581,70.1643,341.1773,70.879,336.6449,73.1299,333.5813,75.1391,324.6186,76.5981,322.6315,75.9427,319.0891,73.7015,314.885,71.0639,315.6348,68.7048,315.4588,66.8973,313.0831,64.8622,312.0635,62.588,314.0142,60.2312,313.6305,59.4861,311.8591,59.3915,309.8048,58.5233,310.2041,57.1819,306.9144,55.9804,304.6804,54.7702,305.2319,53.7273,307.7332,52.9357,308.4628,52.2243,308.0011,51.7205,306.5029,51.7495,304.1552,50.3598,302.5798,48.5193,302.1408,47.1988,300.7148,46.6004,299.0278,47.0595,297.2437,46.8711,295.7553,46.0584,294.7485,44.4314,292.7755,41.4764,288.6933,39.1997,287.4471,37.851,287.5118,36.7221,289.2538,36.0606,290.9985,36.0011,292.6594,35.2362,292.395,34.126,291.207,33.2023,288.424,33.016,287.009,32.3231,286.5059,31.2666,287.0896,29.6223,286.582,27.3683,285.1771,25.5062,283.101,23.9449,281.0469,22.801,279.4373,21.4068,279.1821,19.6473,279.7551,18.2109,280.9496,17.7421,282.622,17.1833,283.2966,16.1546,283.0965,15.0372,281.5283,14.0053,280.0909,12.9151,278.6961,11.5975,277.0707,10.5385,275.4225,9.5688,273.4622,8.5487,270.9916,7.3738,269.3157,5.7621,268.8705,4.4507,269.5389,3.1987,271.0927,2.6855,273.2811,2.5608,275.4739,3.3006,278.1912,5.078,281.909,8.5271,284.1697,11.3576,286.2251,14.0132,286.3233,15.1915,286.1158,15.51,285.7599,16.6912,286.7631,18.2914,287.1951,19.3787,286.9849,20.8446,289.3257,22.5391,291.9464,25.4127,292.4286,28.5332,293.4593,30.5996,297.223,32.4772,299.7133,35.0595,303.4745,35.0807,304.1266,34.0245,303.6819,30.327,300.8895,28.8322,296.8912,28.3993,294.9144,27.6937,294.5657,26.614,296.1041,25.9037,297.3739,25.6845,297.8246,24.471,295.94,22.7956,293.0649,21.4866,291.1229,20.8588,290.324,19.7277,290.6364,18.7692,292.0849,18.3219,293.1902,17.8198,293.1968,16.4933,292.2117,15.0311,290.2679,13.8513,288.7569,12.59,288.6076,10.9218,288.7328,9.7665,287.2839,8.8429,285.582,8.1189,284.291,7.0396,283.2366,5.8411,282.9327,3.8283,282.5522,3.2275,280.8435,2.7268,279.3674,2.2532,278.3224,1.3453,278.2314,0.7429,279.1609,1.5654,279.5029,0.9574,279.897,-0.2562,281.6814,-0.8823,283.4665,-1.5073,284.0658,-2.4642,282.9599,-3.4894,281.1068,-3.6991,279.049,-4.0172,278.1079,-5.1256,278.2582,-6.799,279.0976,-9.4057,278.6578,-11.646,277.317,-14.1578,276.16,-16.6976,275.896,-19.1108,275.5302,-21.837,274.9452,-24.2398,272.9984,-26.4299,270.0613,-28.0668,268.2229,-29.8114,268.5228,-30.2623,267.9381,-32.132,267.1568,-33.2373,265.0719,-33.605,262.2933,-32.3327,261.2061,-30.0066,261.2532,-27.8653,261.7517,-26.3868,262.0161,-24.8538,263.5809,-22.8788,265.0658,-21.1691,265.8074,-19.415,266.6842,-18.7916,268.0278,-18.7995,268.7521,-17.491,268.3084,-15.3906,266.9707,-13.3787,264.9872,-12.4603,262.4372,-12.2113,260.5499,-13.2122,258.4769,-14.8956,256.1174,-16.7507,254.465,-18.3043,253.6343,-20.3552,254.1778,-21.5124,254.1778,-21.5124,254.1778,-21.5124]
```

```js
const json = '{ "galaxy": [  ["gold", 254.1778, -21.5124, 253.6146, -22.5310, 253.2638, -27.7008, 251.9368, -29.7742, 249.7919, -29.7867, 247.8000, -28.4406, 246.5570, -26.9571, 244.6278, -25.8787, 242.5067, -26.0070, 241.5945, -25.3687, 240.7208, -23.0525, 239.5973, -22.3533, 238.6863, -23.5322, 238.7180, -25.7313, 239.4131, -28.0723, 238.6475, -30.8747, 239.9512, -34.4963, 240.4545, -37.0030, 238.8220, -39.1709, 235.6101, -41.6744, 234.5926, -42.9833, 235.6221, -44.6917, 235.5743, -46.4283, 232.6913, -48.4186, 228.3087, -49.7552, 225.9823, -50.6267, 221.4249, -52.5289, 216.0338, -54.6596, 209.0229, -55.3209, 202.9102, -56.0362, 196.2626, -56.3616, 191.7337, -57.1169, 184.7426, -59.1857, 180.5514, -58.8402, 175.1997, -58.5802, 170.6339, -57.6749, 168.3549, -56.2380, 163.3607, -54.7001, 159.2106, -51.3301, 154.8495, -47.2975, 150.0574, -45.2411, 146.8211, -44.7221, 145.5418, -45.4794, 145.6709, -46.1571, 149.5391, -48.3145, 150.7915, -49.6707, 150.0747, -51.0247, 147.4159, -49.8497, 144.3472, -47.8592, 142.7713, -47.5886, 142.7304, -48.1825, 141.8590, -48.7921, 143.8702, -51.7563, 146.7533, -53.8733, 146.7337, -54.7900, 145.4937, -55.0315, 136.3994, -53.7185, 133.1890, -53.9932, 132.3952, -55.2722, 133.9782, -56.3603, 137.5581, -56.8447, 142.3823, -56.7640, 147.1253, -56.7384, 149.2668, -57.3424, 151.0831, -57.4354, 153.9265, -58.4216, 157.9421, -58.9774, 159.0422, -59.6771, 157.5067, -60.3507, 155.1830, -59.7783, 151.9601, -59.2083, 149.2887, -59.3163, 148.3379, -59.9243, 149.9157, -61.4340, 154.0475, -62.1249, 155.9994, -62.2575, 159.2582, -63.5263, 165.5091, -63.4204, 167.1619, -62.8290, 170.1596, -61.3662, 172.9661, -61.4156, 176.0518, -62.9133, 179.3437, -64.2607, 181.9387, -65.3282, 184.3779, -69.3924, 188.2568, -70.9570, 194.7347, -71.2607, 199.7570, -70.2394, 204.1730, -68.8427, 209.0938, -67.8511, 216.7510, -68.0095, 221.9748, -67.1396, 227.5494, -66.2461, 234.5158, -64.3854, 240.5233, -61.8468, 244.0983, -60.4173, 251.3801, -59.1124, 253.2926, -57.4685, 254.7774, -56.3244, 261.4819, -54.4899, 265.8676, -50.8482, 268.8085, -48.0793, 269.9543, -46.3469, 270.5405, -43.6313, 270.6492, -42.3809, 271.0668, -41.1083, 273.1271, -38.6387, 274.8287, -36.5477, 276.5511, -33.8477, 275.4040, -33.1596, 275.2727, -30.5290, 276.8968, -28.1703, 277.9533, -25.4297, 278.6386, -22.3113, 279.4081, -19.7351, 280.9230, -17.4472, 281.9964, -15.6719, 282.8788, -13.6664, 283.3409, -11.0282, 284.5659, -8.4787, 285.8740, -5.6156, 287.7313, -3.1057, 289.7038, -1.0941, 290.4044, -0.0164, 290.7342, 1.1813, 291.9363, 0.4122, 292.8626, 0.7917, 295.5690, 0.8033, 297.0695, 1.1497, 297.0874, 2.1407, 295.9694, 2.3815, 294.6764, 2.5679, 294.4415, 3.7745, 295.0541, 5.1814, 296.9021, 5.9879, 297.7330, 6.5454, 297.6053, 8.4351, 298.6240, 10.2040, 298.1628, 13.5562, 299.1257, 15.5289, 302.8713, 15.4981, 305.5156, 16.1286, 308.1366, 16.6469, 308.7496, 18.5262, 307.5513, 19.8431, 307.7080, 20.7394, 309.0176, 21.5802, 308.7945, 23.5149, 309.4605, 24.2478, 310.5891, 24.9863, 310.3480, 26.0982, 308.9284, 26.8788, 309.1600, 27.5971, 311.8741, 29.1431, 313.3279, 32.0552, 313.9435, 35.1102, 314.9513, 36.1769, 319.2157, 38.0107, 320.5720, 39.7440, 321.0403, 40.9232, 321.8310, 41.6873, 323.6238, 44.8754, 325.1386, 46.0919, 328.0798, 46.8738, 332.6317, 47.1238, 338.1292, 47.4766, 344.7038, 47.6502, 346.4796, 47.7702, 351.3753, 46.7280, 355.1420, 46.2097, 359.5920, 46.1929, 4.3035, 46.2481, 8.0516, 45.6862, 10.5201, 45.7218, 12.3781, 45.1055, 16.3043, 45.2972, 19.0389, 44.8213, 23.6309, 45.0223, 30.7979, 43.0638, 32.8210, 42.8635, 40.6571, 43.7653, 43.6189, 43.8484, 46.6891, 42.5931, 45.3773, 41.6641, 41.7099, 41.8080, 39.3969, 41.6311, 36.5579, 40.8644, 36.3328, 39.9578, 39.0080, 38.9254, 43.4828, 39.0665, 47.0254, 39.2746, 50.5370, 39.3676, 53.6788, 39.5428, 55.7670, 38.8688, 57.1481, 37.3216, 57.2361, 35.7482, 56.6404, 33.7143, 57.1765, 32.1478, 58.8043, 30.8405, 59.9439, 30.9968, 61.4966, 33.3066, 61.4994, 36.0547, 61.1808, 38.6650, 61.7684, 40.0026, 63.8402, 40.1004, 71.4989, 34.6769, 75.3343, 31.9184, 79.7168, 29.0407, 81.0519, 25.1195, 82.1320, 22.0941, 83.6308, 17.4698, 85.5679, 15.1690, 86.9568, 12.6324, 87.7444, 8.8192, 91.3008, 6.1831, 92.8266, 2.6539, 94.6923, -2.1965, 97.7264, -6.0265, 102.5525, -9.6439, 104.6125, -11.6416, 105.1552, -14.2536, 108.2256, -18.5894, 109.6456, -25.3483, 111.2200, -27.2135, 111.2669, -32.1720, 114.7741, -37.8718, 116.9787, -42.4014, 117.0836, -45.1959, 116.1853, -48.6868, 118.8947, -50.1703, 123.5005, -49.9484, 125.9819, -48.8761, 122.1675, -44.3179, 122.4135, -42.9137, 124.6591, -42.8292, 129.1849, -46.1315, 132.5020, -47.4562, 134.3955, -47.4750, 135.7144, -46.3461, 131.5066, -42.8910, 132.0107, -42.0135, 137.8183, -45.2697, 139.3131, -45.0639, 139.6524, -44.1094, 136.9034, -40.6399, 136.6626, -38.9913, 139.6753, -40.1504, 144.8151, -42.6899, 150.5786, -42.3526, 153.6316, -43.0367, 155.7573, -42.5342, 156.1233, -41.0904, 152.5690, -38.5605, 148.4971, -37.7767, 141.2865, -38.2886, 135.1421, -35.9600, 129.8501, -32.1764, 126.2320, -28.4253, 122.1594, -21.3427, 118.5304, -12.7577, 116.3335, -8.7013, 112.8556, -6.4334, 109.1321, -2.3025, 108.1548, 0.0096, 107.9889, 5.4587, 106.7266, 8.9737, 103.4908, 11.8896, 101.3959, 15.0964, 99.5314, 17.7842, 97.6915, 19.7759, 96.9057, 21.2016, 90.6296, 24.9510, 88.0744, 27.4918, 86.0675, 31.0217, 85.2336, 32.7789, 81.6446, 36.8533, 79.8386, 39.1558, 78.6539, 44.2051, 77.5234, 45.5296, 73.0840, 46.1406, 69.0884, 46.5652, 66.4784, 48.5322, 65.0187, 50.6773, 63.1096, 51.4737, 60.4311, 51.8441, 60.2604, 52.7052, 63.6488, 52.7609, 65.6099, 53.0495, 68.0178, 52.7517, 68.0826, 53.7533, 63.1671, 54.9872, 57.4967, 55.4868, 58.4393, 56.1385, 60.5618, 56.2369, 62.6651, 56.7553, 62.6924, 57.7129, 59.3107, 59.2013, 50.7444, 59.4785, 45.7503, 59.6435, 43.3097, 60.6511, 38.7256, 61.5348, 35.7107, 62.5099, 30.2614, 62.7058, 27.5803, 63.4145, 23.1877, 65.0421, 18.5579, 65.6747, 13.7778, 67.5849, 11.2150, 68.1610, 7.5359, 67.6326, 5.1034, 66.7569, 2.2150, 66.1991, 0.2476, 66.2511, 355.2714, 64.4260, 350.1006, 62.9385, 344.4302, 62.4847, 339.3002, 60.4931, 333.4702, 58.8851, 331.1327, 59.4605, 330.9382, 61.9623, 340.6152, 65.1092, 343.2879, 66.7647, 343.3581, 70.1643, 341.1773, 70.8790, 336.6449, 73.1299, 333.5813, 75.1391, 324.6186, 76.5981, 322.6315, 75.9427, 319.0891, 73.7015, 314.8850, 71.0639, 315.6348, 68.7048, 315.4588, 66.8973, 313.0831, 64.8622, 312.0635, 62.5880, 314.0142, 60.2312, 313.6305, 59.4861, 311.8591, 59.3915, 309.8048, 58.5233, 310.2041, 57.1819, 306.9144, 55.9804, 304.6804, 54.7702, 305.2319, 53.7273, 307.7332, 52.9357, 308.4628, 52.2243, 308.0011, 51.7205, 306.5029, 51.7495, 304.1552, 50.3598, 302.5798, 48.5193, 302.1408, 47.1988, 300.7148, 46.6004, 299.0278, 47.0595, 297.2437, 46.8711, 295.7553, 46.0584, 294.7485, 44.4314, 292.7755, 41.4764, 288.6933, 39.1997, 287.4471, 37.8510, 287.5118, 36.7221, 289.2538, 36.0606, 290.9985, 36.0011, 292.6594, 35.2362, 292.3950, 34.1260, 291.2070, 33.2023, 288.4240, 33.0160, 287.0090, 32.3231, 286.5059, 31.2666, 287.0896, 29.6223, 286.5820, 27.3683, 285.1771, 25.5062, 283.1010, 23.9449, 281.0469, 22.8010, 279.4373, 21.4068, 279.1821, 19.6473, 279.7551, 18.2109, 280.9496, 17.7421, 282.6220, 17.1833, 283.2966, 16.1546, 283.0965, 15.0372, 281.5283, 14.0053, 280.0909, 12.9151, 278.6961, 11.5975, 277.0707, 10.5385, 275.4225, 9.5688, 273.4622, 8.5487, 270.9916, 7.3738, 269.3157, 5.7621, 268.8705, 4.4507, 269.5389, 3.1987, 271.0927, 2.6855, 273.2811, 2.5608, 275.4739, 3.3006, 278.1912, 5.0780, 281.9090, 8.5271, 284.1697, 11.3576, 286.2251, 14.0132, 286.3233, 15.1915, 286.1158, 15.5100, 285.7599, 16.6912, 286.7631, 18.2914, 287.1951, 19.3787, 286.9849, 20.8446, 289.3257, 22.5391, 291.9464, 25.4127, 292.4286, 28.5332, 293.4593, 30.5996, 297.2230, 32.4772, 299.7133, 35.0595, 303.4745, 35.0807, 304.1266, 34.0245, 303.6819, 30.3270, 300.8895, 28.8322, 296.8912, 28.3993, 294.9144, 27.6937, 294.5657, 26.6140, 296.1041, 25.9037, 297.3739, 25.6845, 297.8246, 24.4710, 295.9400, 22.7956, 293.0649, 21.4866, 291.1229, 20.8588, 290.3240, 19.7277, 290.6364, 18.7692, 292.0849, 18.3219, 293.1902, 17.8198, 293.1968, 16.4933, 292.2117, 15.0311, 290.2679, 13.8513, 288.7569, 12.5900, 288.6076, 10.9218, 288.7328, 9.7665, 287.2839, 8.8429, 285.5820, 8.1189, 284.2910, 7.0396, 283.2366, 5.8411, 282.9327, 3.8283, 282.5522, 3.2275, 280.8435, 2.7268, 279.3674, 2.2532, 278.3224, 1.3453, 278.2314, 0.7429, 279.1609, 1.5654, 279.5029, 0.9574, 279.8970, -0.2562, 281.6814, -0.8823, 283.4665, -1.5073, 284.0658, -2.4642, 282.9599, -3.4894, 281.1068, -3.6991, 279.0490, -4.0172, 278.1079, -5.1256, 278.2582, -6.7990, 279.0976, -9.4057, 278.6578, -11.6460, 277.3170, -14.1578, 276.1600, -16.6976, 275.8960, -19.1108, 275.5302, -21.8370, 274.9452, -24.2398, 272.9984, -26.4299, 270.0613, -28.0668, 268.2229, -29.8114, 268.5228, -30.2623, 267.9381, -32.1320, 267.1568, -33.2373, 265.0719, -33.6050, 262.2933, -32.3327, 261.2061, -30.0066, 261.2532, -27.8653, 261.7517, -26.3868, 262.0161, -24.8538, 263.5809, -22.8788, 265.0658, -21.1691, 265.8074, -19.4150, 266.6842, -18.7916, 268.0278, -18.7995, 268.7521, -17.4910, 268.3084, -15.3906, 266.9707, -13.3787, 264.9872, -12.4603, 262.4372, -12.2113, 260.5499, -13.2122, 258.4769, -14.8956, 256.1174, -16.7507, 254.4650, -18.3043, 253.6343, -20.3552, 254.1778, -21.5124, 254.1778, -21.5124, 254.1778, -21.5124],  ["#purple", 257.4284, -35.0782, 258.7567, -34.6776, 259.6113, -33.6806, 259.9750, -32.7946, 260.9776, -32.5946, 263.4189, -33.7211, 265.2841, -35.1551, 267.0684, -37.0106, 266.5317, -38.4758, 264.8234, -39.1661, 263.0403, -38.8168, 260.6629, -38.1140, 258.3247, -38.4735, 255.5110, -38.1878, 254.0470, -37.3602, 253.5295, -36.1222, 253.7763, -35.4603, 254.7476, -35.1875, 256.2938, -35.0264, 257.4284, -35.0782, 257.4284, -35.0782, 257.4284, -35.0782],  ["yellow", 254.4847, -39.5230, 255.2762, -39.2671, 257.3657, -39.9243, 258.7042, -41.3823, 258.3749, -43.2682, 257.0644, -43.3665, 254.3218, -40.8215, 254.6242, -40.4285, 254.4847, -39.5230, 254.4847, -39.5230, 254.4847, -39.5230],   ["gray", 247.9505, -43.8132, 247.7714, -42.7233, 248.2105, -41.7101, 249.7280, -40.8373, 248.8720, -37.3180, 247.1054, -36.2799, 245.6020, -36.7984, 243.1195, -35.6949, 242.2253, -36.0340, 241.9943, -38.6050, 241.6221, -40.6326, 239.8163, -43.0489, 238.8334, -44.6762, 238.5119, -46.8016, 237.7857, -49.0401, 236.8718, -50.6695, 237.0713, -52.3828, 238.9693, -53.2821, 241.4236, -52.3398, 244.7950, -51.3601, 248.9798, -51.6343, 253.4436, -51.0624, 257.8767, -50.6966, 260.9423, -50.2581, 261.6140, -49.2459, 260.7624, -46.4869, 260.5888, -45.3986, 259.8614, -44.8904, 257.7870, -44.9484, 256.1962, -45.7995, 256.3613, -48.5425, 253.5419, -49.9573, 249.8040, -49.5087, 248.3220, -49.4156, 245.7227, -48.7635, 244.6261, -48.0299, 245.6396, -46.7119, 247.9407, -46.1849, 251.5170, -45.7312, 252.8143, -45.1508, 251.9638, -44.5626, 249.5206, -44.4962, 247.9505, -43.8132, 247.9505, -43.8132, 247.9505, -43.8132],   ["pink", 231.8281, -52.4833, 233.5614, -52.5365, 234.4273, -52.7145, 236.0044, -53.8647, 236.5304, -55.8352, 237.3389, -57.1286, 230.3741, -58.8315, 226.4955, -59.1351, 221.0867, -60.4628, 220.9820, -59.2769, 221.7242, -59.0271, 223.2728, -57.1869, 226.5641, -55.0286, 228.1040, -54.5097, 229.9674, -52.9922, 231.8281, -52.4833, 231.8281, -52.4833, 231.8281, -52.4833], ["green", 191.9931, -60.9308, 195.0383, -60.9157, 197.2513, -61.5730, 197.6589, -63.3081, 193.3910, -65.2609, 190.6198, -65.3102, 189.1651, -65.7997, 187.9019, -65.8296, 187.4866, -64.7787, 188.0292, -64.2788, 187.2718, -63.6037, 188.0759, -62.2722, 190.6559, -61.1093, 191.9931, -60.9308, 191.9931, -60.9308],  ["orange", 132.7337, -37.5805, 133.0861, -38.9333, 132.3284, -39.7468, 129.7569, -39.4258, 127.1207, -38.0660, 124.9328, -36.1447, 124.8899, -34.6079, 124.7196, -32.9119, 125.9376, -32.1253, 127.3543, -32.6954, 128.6915, -33.7875, 129.6263, -35.1366, 131.7847, -36.5415, 132.7337, -37.5805, 132.7337, -37.5805],["red", 121.1825, -39.3994, 119.9070, -39.0295, 119.2840, -37.6001, 119.3245, -36.1550, 117.3621, -34.3430, 116.3134, -31.1424, 115.5167, -28.5014, 115.3112, -26.0891, 115.8367, -24.7060, 117.0334, -24.5218, 117.8897, -25.7087, 118.5145, -28.1509, 119.6664, -31.5362, 121.7083, -34.8713, 122.3366, -37.4519, 122.1419, -39.0037, 121.1825, -39.3994, 121.1825, -39.3994],["#396bad", 305.9982, 40.1858, 309.8895, 39.3472, 311.2759, 37.2754, 311.2100, 35.4356, 310.1900, 34.7837, 308.6971, 34.9849, 307.5461, 36.5500, 305.0697, 37.7876, 304.5142, 39.0978, 305.1288, 40.0209, 305.9982, 40.1858] ]}';
function diff(a, b) {
    return Math.abs(a - b);
}

const obj = JSON.parse(json);
var canvas = document.getElementById("result");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var counter = 0;
var prevX = 254.1778;
var prevY = -21.5124;
var newX, newY;
for (var i = 0; i < 1 /*obj.galaxy.length*/ ; i++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = obj.galaxy[i][0];
    counter = 0;
    while (obj.galaxy[i][1 + counter + 2] <= obj.galaxy[i].length) {
        newX = obj.galaxy[i][1 + counter];
        newY = obj.galaxy[i][2 + counter];
        ctx.lineTo(newX, newY + 100);
        if (diff(newX, prevX) > 10 || diff(newY, prevY) > 10) {
            console.log("Diff found at " + counter + " with newX: " + newX + "and newY: " + newY + " and oldX: " + prevX + "and oldY: " + prevY);
        }
        prevX = newX;
        prevY = newY;
        counter += 2;

    }
    ctx.fill();
}



for (j = 0; j < 1 /*obj.galaxy.length*/ ; j++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    counter = 0;
    while (obj.galaxy[j][1 + counter + 2] <= obj.galaxy[j].length) {
        newX = obj.galaxy[j][1 + counter];
        newY = obj.galaxy[j][2 + counter];
        if (counter >= 342 && counter < 624) newX += 360;
        ctx.lineTo(newX, newY + 300);
        counter += 2;
    }
    ctx.fill();
}

for (j = 0; j < 1 /*obj.galaxy.length*/ ; j++) {
    counter = 0;
    while (obj.galaxy[j][1 + counter + 2] <= obj.galaxy[j].length) {
        if (counter >= 342 && counter < 624) obj.galaxy[j][1 + counter] += 360;
        counter += 2;
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj.galaxy[0]));
}
```

```html
<canvas id="result" width="640" height="450" style="position: absolute;border: 1px solid;"></canvas>
```